# Can i simply put dll library to the Windows folder?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

I am using Qt in my C++ application. I'm using dynamic linking so it comes with few dll files like:

- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5WinExtras.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll
- Qt5Network.dll

Thats much files and I would like to simply have a one "exe" file in the main folder. I'm using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) installer and I would like to install these dll files directly to the `Windows/System32` folder because I tested it and it will be working just fine that way.

The question is - should I do that? I mean, wouldn't it be fragile and will it work on every Windows system without any problems?

Comment: no, as this can affect other applications based on Qt. If you want single exe - use qt as static library and compile it into your exe

Comment: Or add the Qt*.dll files to the same folder as your main application.

Comment: I don't want it static or in the same folder because I'm having a second app that is using Qt as well and i would have to use same libs twice! Thats a waste of space and doesnt look cool.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: What if you release a new version of one of the two apps, and that new version also uses a new Qt version? What you are proposing has a name, _DLL Hell_.

Comment: You can add your shared DLLs to a common folder and use an application manifest to reference them.  Application manifests are not just for managed code but can be used to load the correct dll(s) from the right place at runtime.

Comment: @MSalters Well, these two apps are kinda connected since the first one is an updater for the second :D

Comment: If so then why cant you put all of them to the same location. The two exe files and the libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a really good idea for multiple reasons :

- Other Qt applications might be built using a different version of Qt. These will not work anymore. If you right click Qt5Core.dll you can see the version of qt used to build this lib.
- Your application can't control the dll anymore, other application could potentially delete/update these lib : your app would not work anymore
- new version of your application might not be able to coexist with old ones if using different version. Mostly problematic for you (for testing purposes)

If you really want to deploy a single exe, I recommend to make a stand-alone executable : https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows

Legally, you should allow the user to be able to edit the Qt libs and use a personalised one, for this reasons, the best way is to create a deployement package that contains all dll alongside the exe

Comment: Beautiful answer my man. I hope you have a wonderful day. I wish you a beautiful wife and cluster of kids.

Answer (score 0):

Coping the Qt frameworks .dll files to the windows folder is not an good idea. Because they could be deleted/modified/overwritten or updated by other applications. So the best practice is copy them to the same location as the app will be installed. Later on if u provide a new update of your app so you can just deliver the new exe and replace the old one. 
 If you are developing two applications which uses the same core libraries and you want to keep the framework libraries in one place and common for the both programs I suggest put them in a separate location and update the windows registry to point to it `(Not modifying the PATH variable itself as it may affect the other programs)`, and then then try to load the library s from there. but I'm not sure how to do that.

**EDIT**

In Qt you can use `QLibrary` to link librarys at runtime. refer http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibrary.html to use that.

LIBS= links libraries (either static libraries or stubs for dynamic libraries) into the executable, so that your code calls the functions normally and any dynamic libraries are loaded automatically during start-up. So if these library s are not found the application crashes at startup.

Use QLibrary to load the library s at runtime. get the library location programmatically from a registry value.

Comment: Nice solution my man, I'm wondering how could I do that: `update the windows registry to point to it`

Comment: If your using INNO to build the installer here is how to write the windows registry from it [link](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection)

Comment: @DonaldDuck I updated my answer. Its my suggestion for your question if you need to shear the same library s between two application. If This was the solution you were looking for, mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Well I might find that useful, but the problem is that you can't load Qt libraries itself right in the QLibrary since compiled Qt application require the core dlls at runtime and there is no way to get around it except using static libraries (which is illegal for commercial use) or modify the `PATH` environment (which is fragile, since it has limits)